# How do I create a conda env from a yml with no default packages?

Tags: python, conda

I want to describe all my deps in a yml file:

I can do this and run this command: `conda env create -f environment.yml`

This installs a bunch of extra rubbish I don't want.

But I can run this command to create a minimal conda env: `conda create --name test-layers python --no-default-packages`

OK so now I want to use my yml config.

This doesn't work: `conda create --name myenv -f environment.yml --no-default-packages --yes`

Error: `PackagesNotFoundError: The following packages are not available from current channels: -environment.yml`

And this doesn't work: `conda env create -f environment.yml --no-default-packages`

Error: `unrecognized arguments: --no-default-packages`

How do I use a yml file and also not install a bunch of default packages?

### Edit

I feel like I'm missing something because the tooling can't be this obtuse and stupid. I thought I would try to create the env first and then update from a file to see if at least that worked:

```
conda create --name myenv python --no-default-packages --yes
conda env update --name myenv --file environment.yml
```

And now my env has all those default packages I wanted to avoid! Am I seriously going to have to wrap this in a script that parses my environment.yaml and runs a command to install each dep and pip package myself?

Answer (score 0):

Did you try using `--no-deps`? as in:

```
conda create --name myenv -f environment.yml --no-deps --yes
```

Comment: `If you wish to skip dependency checking altogether, use the '--no-deps' option. This may result in an environment with incompatible packages, so this option must be used with great caution.` - how does that help me? I want dep checking just not any default packages im not using